# Windows 8 with C++ directx9 debug output

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx-9

I have a game that I need to figure out a specific issue.

When you maximize, move or resize the window the DirectX device resets. But before it resets all graphically allocated objects should be released that are not part of the managed pool.
As for this game there seems to be 30 unreleased objects when the application quits (from basic directx debug library output) which leads me to assume that when the device is reset, the same issue occurs. This causes the game to crash when you maximize, move or resize the window which is obviously not acceptable.

More research has resulted in that you can enable excessive debugging in DirectX via DirectX Control Panel, except if you have Windows 8 no such thing is available. You can install the DirectX sdk and open the DirectX Control Panel, but all the features on Direct3D tab is grayed out. This excessive debug output level would then print out the addresses of allocations that have not been released upon exit, which could give me a clue of what is actually not released during a reset device event.

The game is built in C++ using DirectX 9 libraries with Visual Studio 2010.
Ps. Windows 8 comes with DirectX SDK by default but no control panel options, you must manually install the DirectX SDK to get it.

My question is, how can I enable excessive directx debugging on my environment (Windows 8 Pro)?
Are there any way you could potentially enable excessive debugging per application in the source while its compiled with directx debug libraries, or must you use the DirectX Control Panel for that?

Cheers, Nicco.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable some debugging through the registry as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also, I played around with the control panel and noticed it modifies the following keys on my (windows7) machine:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\ControlPanel
```

Checking "Use Debug Version of Direct3D9" in the control panel set the "LoadDebugRuntime" registry key to a value of 1 (otherwise it was 0).

Checking "Break On Memory Leak" set the "BreakOnMemLeak" key to 1.
Checking "Break On D3D Error" set the "BreakOnDPF" key to 1.

Note that these same keys were also duplicated at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\
```

So if you don't have the control panel installed they might work there as well.